# Angular cli with es6 instead of Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

I wanted to know if there is any option to use es6 transpiler like
babel instead of type script in an angular cli project.

Is there any flag for script language like you can do with `--style`?

Thanks.

Comment: No, it generates boilerplate framework from a set of templates but these are typescript only.

Answer (score 0):

NO, Angular CLI doesn't allow this.

Theoretically you can write Angular 2+ code in JavaScript, But the framework itself is written in TypeScript and all the code examples is in TypeScript so you'll be "alone in the dark" if you will decide to do that.